# Create new column based on computation of other column data in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which holds the data  with columns method_path,column_path. I also have a list of strings say method_list.Now the functionality is to check for each row in the data frame and check if any string in d is a substring of method_path and if it is then populate now column called match_found in the array with the string from method_list that passed condition else populate it as NaN.I tried using apply function,but it seems to be taking some much time on a big data frame.Any alternatives available.

```
df_final['column_match'] = df_final.apply(lambda x: get_match_check(method_list, x.method_path), axis=1)
```

```
def get_match_check(list, string, classList, classString):
    return next((e for e in list if " "+e+" " in string), None)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few faster options (timings below):

1. Convert your [`DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

   ```
   df.method_path.apply(lambda mp: next((ml for ml in method_list if ml in mp), None))
   ```
2. Or switch to [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

   ```
   regex = '|'.join(method_list)
   df['match'] = df.method_path.str.extract(r'(' + regex + r')')
   ```
3. Or if you want all matches, use [`Series.str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html):

   ```
   df['match'] = df.method_path.str.findall(r'(' + regex + r')')
   ```
4. Or if you want the matches to be comma separated, chain [`Series.str.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

   ```
   df['match'] = df.method_path.str.findall(r'(' + regex + r')').str.join(',')
   ```

#### Toy example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'method_path': ['foo bar', 'cat in the hat', 'hello world'], 'column_path': ['abc', 'mno', 'xyz']})

method_list = ['foo', 'cat', 'hat']
regex = '|'.join(method_list)

df['apply'] = df.method_path.apply(lambda x: next((e for e in method_list if e in x), None))
df['match'] = df.method_path.str.extract(r'(' + regex + r')')
df['matches'] = df.method_path.str.findall(r'(' + regex + r')')
df['matches_csv'] = df.method_path.str.findall(r'(' + regex + r')').str.join(',')
```

```
      method_path  column_path  apply  match     matches  matches_csv
0         foo bar          abc    foo    foo       [foo]          foo
1  cat in the hat          mno    cat    cat  [cat, hat]      cat,hat
2     hello world          xyz   None    NaN          []
```

#### Timings

[image: timings]

Comment: Hell yes!, this is the kind of answer you dream of doing someday in SO :') +10